# VBScript reading specifc line from array

Tags: arrays, csv, vbscript

I'm fairly inexperienced with arrays, but I have a CSV file and I want to grab a specific piece of data from it.  For example, I understand how to iterate through the data from the 2nd column, but how do I grab the data 3 rows down in that column?  How can I modify this to achieve it?  I can't find anything on Google, so I'm wondering if I'm asking the wrong question...

```
dim fs,objTextFile
set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim arrStr
set objTextFile = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\CSVfile.csv")

Do while NOT objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  arrStr = split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",")
'strUser = arrStr(0)
strFullName = arrStr(1)
'wscript.echo strUser
wscript.echo strFullName
Loop

objTextFile.Close
set objTextFile = Nothing
set fs = Nothing
```

For example, if my csv looked like this:

```
userID, fullname, address 
a1, Tom Green, 123 Apple St 
a2, Chad Mendez, 456 Book Ave 
a3, Ville Valo, 789 Cat Way
```

How would I grab the data "Chad Mendez"?

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, came up with this and it seems to work.  So easy, it's dumb - I was overthinking it:

```
dim fs,objTextFile
set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim arrStr
set objTextFile = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\CSV.csv")

rownumber = 1

Do while NOT objTextFile.AtEndOfStream

  arrStr = split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",")
'strUser = arrStr(0)
strFullName = arrStr(1)
'wscript.echo strUser
'wscript.echo strFullName

if rownumber = 3 then

name = strFullName

wscript.echo name

end if

rownumber = rownumber + 1

Loop

objTextFile.Close
set objTextFile = Nothing
set fs = Nothing
```